# Searching content of string using PHP associative array notation

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative

I have access to two different servers where I'm running the same code:

```
<?php
   $foo = '#f12345';
   if (isset($foo['acf'])) { 
      echo "acf is set: " . $foo['acf']; 
   } else { 
      echo 'acf not set'; 
   }
?>
```

On one server, running PHP 5.6.21, the result is:

```
acf is set: f
```

On the other server, running PHP 5.6.25, the result is:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'acf' in...
```

I tried but failed to find an explanation online for this behaviour. Would it be a PHP.ini setting?

It seems that, in the server running PHP 5.6.21, the code is being interpreted as a regex search for either a, c, or f (I changed the "f" in $foo to both "a" and "c" and got similar results) and not a search for the index "acf" of an associative array.

Can someone shed some light on why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider adding the is_array() check:

if (is_array($foo) && isset($foo['acf'])) {

Comment: You probably have error reporting disabled in the first server.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script and you'll get the warning in both.

Comment: I tried a number of different versions of PHP, from 5.3 to 7.1, and they all said "acf not set".

Comment: I apologize... the issue is not the warning in itself. The issue is that in the server running PHP 5.6.25 i get "acf not set". How can it be set in one, not set in the other?

Comment: @DentraAndres Please see my updated answer below.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the behaviour of accessing strings through offsets changed in version 5.4. Before version 5.4 string based offsets like `"foo"` was silently converted to `0`, while after version 5.4 a warning is thrown. It looks like you have found a bug in that change, where 5.6.21 has the old behaviour, and 5.6.25 has the new behaviour. There seems to be a slight variance though, as the character `#` is really in position `[0]`

Documentet here in the official docs : [PHP.NET Language Types Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) Scroll down to "String access and modification by character"

> As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown. Previously an offset like "foo" was silently cast to 0.

Comment: There's no difference between single and double quotes unless you have variables or escape sequences inside.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: @Barmar Corrected my answer based on documentation.

Comment: @Barmar If you still feel my answer is wrong now, please inform me of what the problem is so I can fix it. If not, remove your downvote.

Comment: Downvote removed. Can you add a link to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: @Barmar Done. Also added a block quote from the relevant section.